# error while installing android studio on linux mint

Tags: android, android-studio, linux-mint

when i tried to install andoid studio on linux mint this error `"bash: ./studio.sh: Permission denied"` shows

```
vikram@vikram-Inspiron-5520 ~/android-studio/bin $ ./studio.sh
```

> bash: ./studio.sh: Permission denied

Comment: Update the question with the output of `ls -l ~/android-studio/bin`

Answer (score 0):

instead  bash: ./studio.sh 
use      sudo bash: ./studio.sh